# Where flash is stored in rails and how to keep them for several requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails where exactly the flash is stored like it is stored in a table or something and how can we make the flash be available in any specific no of requests. ????

p.s: i know how to use flash.keep but looking for any other answer then that because i don't want to mention .keep in every controller

Comment: Is their any way i can get all the flash created till know in a login session or something like that

Comment: user `session` instead of `flash`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash_rb.html),

> The flash provides a way to pass temporary objects between actions.
>   **Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the very next
>   action and then cleared out**. This is a great way of doing notices and
>   alerts, such as a create action that sets `flash[:notice] = "Post
>   successfully created"` before redirecting to a display action that can
>   then expose the flash to its template. Actually, that exposure is
>   automatically done

Notice what I marked above in bold - so, yes, as Salil mentioned, storing in the `session` would be an alternative approach.  That said, it may not be the *best place* to store these.

Comment: just searched more found out that we can also store it in tables by making certain changes in config files

Comment: Yup, that's also an option =)